# Sentence Structure - Verb vs Noun Usage

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have been actively learning to write English for over a month. Though I can, some how, manage with grammar, sentence structures are not easy for me. In the sentence below, please any one comment why this usage is not correct or it is.

**Original:**
" De Mestral patented Velcro in 1955, subsequently refining and developing its practical manufacture until *its commercial introduction* in the late 1950s "

**Modified :**
" De Mestral patented Velcro in 1955, subsequently refining and developing its practical manufacture until *it was commercially introduced* in the late 1950s "

Also, please answer which is the most preferred one in the written English and why ?

Comment: Both equally grammatical and natural-sounding. Equivalent in meaning. No reason to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two sentences are correct. Because here after **until** we are expecting an event, "*until what?*", so here the two sentences express the event of *the commercial introduction of the manufacture*.

So here **its commercial introduction** and **it was commercially introduced** are similar and describe the wanted event in two different ways.

But the first one is more appropriate because referring to [**the until/till section here**](http://www.world-english.org/prepositions.htm) after **until** we usually expect a noun:

### *Structure: Until, till*:

*until/till + noun describing time/date: examples: next week, this evening, tomorrow.*

e.g. Tom's wife will stay here **until/till the end of next week**.

**Until/till the end of the month**, you can use my computer.